# laravel automatically casts integers to string

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a laravel 5.6 web application with a mobile API.

The issue is that laravel casts all integers and booleans to string automatically.
I want to know is there any way to fix it?

Interestingly it works fine in local!

Below is an example of API output (the API output is in JSON):

```json
{
        "id": 9,
        "city_id": "1",
        "avatar": "group-377.png",
        "biography": null,
        "username": "mnalci",
        "chosen": "1",
        "blocked": "1",
        "blocked_until": null,
        "is_registered": "1",
        "actived_at": "2020-05-03 00:00:00",
        "created_at": "2020-05-16 13:21:44",
        "updated_at": "2020-05-16 13:21:44",
        "is_followed": "1",
        "is_requested": "0"
},
```

As you see the `city_id` that is defined as an integer in the database is cast to string,
and also all booleans are cast too (like a chosen field).

I find some way to cast the values in models like this

```
protected $casts = [
        'is_registered' => 'boolean' ,
        'blocked' => 'boolean' ,
    ];
```

but I think these must be a better way than casting each field in each model. Its huge project and that would take a lots of time.

Comment: I think there's no better way than the solution you already found :) \

Comment: does anybody know why it's working fine in the local but not in the server?

Answer (score 2):

In my case with Laravel 10, I just need to update config/database with

```php
'mysql' => [
    // Other configuration options...
    'options' => [
        PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES => false,
    ],
],
```

Then let Laravel handle casting all attribute for you without depending on native driver of mysql.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux based servers

just sharing my experience, I have faced the same issue where the production server (Ubuntu) is converting integer to string on response. This way, the mobile app is set to accept integer string instead of actual integer. While my computer (as a development server - Debian 12) does return integer as integer. This way I can't test any changes to the web service locally because of mobile app's data type sensitivity, so that I only test it on REST client app like Postman or Insomnia before deploying for production (maybe risky if there is runtime bug).

After some research I find out that it was not caused by Laravel or difference of PHP version, but it was because of the difference of the sqlserver driver used between my compouter & the production server. I use php-sybase on my computer (which work as expected, returning integer as integer) and the production server seems to use sqlsrv (maybe Microsoft's official driver for linux - which autommatically convert integer to string).

I think you can try to remove all installed PHP sqlserver drivers (if possible, or disable it so you can remove it later) and install php-sybase.