Livewire Laravel Dropdown filter not working after hosting
I have problem with dropdown filter not working after hosting. This is my code
app/Livewire/Matakuliah.php (controller)
return view('livewire.matakuliah', [
            'title' => 'Mata Kuliah',
            'matakuliahs' => $matakuliahs,
            'jurusans' => Jurusan::all(),
            'prodis' => ProgramStudi::where('jurusan_id', $this->jurusan_id)->get(),
        ]);

resource/views/livewire/matakuliahModal.blade.php
<div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <label for="jurusan_id" class="fs_caption4">Jurusan</label>
                        <select class="form-select @error('jurusan_id') is-invalid @enderror select2-add"
                            id="jurusan_id" name="jurusan_id" wire:model.live="jurusan_id" style="width: 100%">
                            <option value="">-Pilih Jurusan-</option>
                            @if (Auth::user()->role->id == 4)
                                @foreach ($jurusans as $jurusan)
                                    @if ($jurusan->id == Auth::user()->jurusan_id)
                                        <option value="{{ $jurusan->id }}">{{ $jurusan->nama_jurusan }}</option>
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach
                            @else
                                @foreach ($jurusans as $jurusan)
                                    <option value="{{ $jurusan->id }}">{{ $jurusan->nama_jurusan }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            @endif
                        </select>
                        @error('jurusan_id')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="program_studi_id" class="fs_caption4">Program Studi</label>
                        <select class="form-select @error('program_studi_id') is-invalid @enderror select2-add"
                            id="program_studi_id" name="program_studi_id" wire:model.live="program_studi_id"
                            style="width: 100%" data-placeholder="-Pilih Program Studi-">
                            <option value="">-Pilih Program Studi-</option>
                            @if (Auth::user()->role->id == 4)
                                @foreach ($prodis as $prodi)
                                    @if ($prodi->id == Auth::user()->program_studi_id)
                                        <option value="{{ $prodi->id }}">{{ $prodi->nama_prodi }}</option>
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach
                            @else
                                @foreach ($prodis as $prodi)
                                    <option value="{{ $prodi->id }}">{{ $prodi->nama_prodi }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            @endif
                        </select>
                        @error('program_studi_id')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>

This is the view of Program Studi Dropdown after hosting the laravel app
The Program Studi dropdown is empty

Program Studi dropdown should be show list filtered by Jurusan. In localhost, the Program Studi Dropdown is working
The Program Studi dropdown is shown

What should i do for fix that problem ?
Thank you so much for helping :)
I expect that Program Studi Dropdown filter by jurusan_id will be work normally in hosting server

I've experienced this between my local and production servers and it was simply because laravel was returning integers on local but strings on production. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77952164/55859

Thank you for your attention, i will try it and i will update it to you.

Hi Gavin, i've tried to change that you suggest 'options' => [
PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES => false,
], But, it still not working for my Program Studi Dropdown. It's still empty on my hosting. Do u have other suggestions ??

Apologies, I think I misunderstood the original issue. Looking at your render function, you are using $this->jurusan_id, which if I recall correctly, is only available on the initial render. I usually use the updated hooks to populate dependent properties (e.g. when jurusan_id is changed, it will fire updated and you can then set prodis which will automatically update the fields)

Can you give the example code ? I don't really understand

It appears you are not using Livewire to the full potential, which may be the cause.
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Component;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\ProgramStudi;
use App\Models\Jurusan;

class YourComponent extends Component
{
    public $prodis = [];
    public $jurusan_id;

    public function updatedJurusanId()
    {
        $this->prodis = ProgramStudi::where('jurusan_id', $this->jurusan_id)->get();
    }

    // Alternative to the above.
    // public function updated($key, $value)
    // {
    //     if ($key === 'jurusan_id')
    //     {
    //         $this->prodis = ProgramStudi::where('jurusan_id', $value)->get();
    //     }
    // }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.matakuliah', [
            'title' => 'Mata Kuliah',
            'matakuliahs' => $matakuliahs,
            'jurusans' => Jurusan::all()
        ]);
    }
}

The above component would automatically populate prodis with values based on the selected jurusan_id.
Livewire listens for changes to these properties and will automatically update the component on the page with the values and allow you to select.
Note, this is pseudo code, so you will need to take bits from it to apply to your existing code.
